# Invalid column name in my web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have urgent and unexplainable problem so any help would be appreciated. I haave 2 different databases which are exactly the same except there is different data in each of them.

I have a web application using LINQ-To-EF and until I've changed the database in connection string everything was working fine. Even though the databases are exactly the same I receive the error: "Invalid column name 'tema_id'." The problem is that "tema_id" doesn't exist in any of those two databases, however, somehow it does exist in .edmx file. The name of the mapping should be "aktivnost_id" and not "tema_id" how it is now.

I've tried updating the model from the database, but in that case everything gets wrong and I get dozens of different errors in Error List.

I've provided the screenshot of mapping details for the problematic table (you can see "tema_id" which should be "aktivnost_id").

I know my explanation might be a bit confusing, but if any additional info is needed I will provide it.

[image: Current mappings]

Comment: The databases are exactly the same except they have different data...lol

Comment: I meant the database design... Even data in it is the same except in one table which is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It I hard to give a complete answer without the full details of the errors that occur when you try to update; however, I would be sorely tempted to edit the EDMX as XML, use "find" to locate `tema_id`, and fix directly.

If nothing else, it is quick to try :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that wasn't the problem, but it is good to know that .edmx is actually XML file and that it can be edited outside of the Visual Studio! ;) The problem was solved by fixing error by error after updating the model.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to edit the .EDMX file directly to match the actual table structure?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried editing the .edmx file, but unfortunately that wasn't solution. I solved the problem by fixing error by error after updating the model.

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate whole data access layer manually outside of visual studio through edmgen.exe

use the following command for EF4 (adjust parameters to reflect your db name, username, password)

`@"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:fullgeneration /c:"Data Source=tcp:127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=your_database;User ID=sa;Password=your_password;Integrated Security=False;" /project:DataContext /entitycontainer:DataContext /namespace:Project /language:CSharp /pluralize`

Comment: Thank you for the answer provided, but it didn't solve my problem. I had to fix error by error after getting the model updated. Cheers!